# How to create a decorator passed as user inputs and process

Tags: python, decorator

return a new function when called returns the results of orignal function

1. f is pow function(2,3) = 8 but it has to take reverse g(3,2) =9
2. cmp(1,2) =1-2 = -1 but it has to cmp(2,1) = 2-1 = 1
3. join_with coder you are >> you are coder
4. capitalize_first_and_join first second third >> THIRDsecondfirst

here `pow, cmp, join_with, capitalize_first_and_join` are function names

user input is below

```
pow 2 3
cmp 1 2
join_with coder you are
capitalize_first_and_join first second third
```

Output

```
9
1
you are coder
THIRDsecondfirst
```

Decorator

```
def reversed_args(f):
    # need to write code here
    return f


int_func_map = {
    'pow': pow,
    'cmp': lambda a, b: 0 if a == b else [1, -1][a < b],
}

string_func_map = {
    'join_with': lambda separator, *args: separator.join(args),
    'capitalize_first_and_join': lambda first, *args: ''.join([first.upper()] + list(args)),
}

queries = int(input())
for _ in range(queries):
    line = input().split()
    func_name, args = line[0], line[1:]
    if func_name in int_func_map:
        args = list(map(int, args))
        print(reversed_args(int_func_map[func_name])(*args))
    else:
        print(reversed_args(string_func_map[func_name])(*args))
```

Comment: It may be me. But have trouble in understanding your question. Can you re-frame it ?

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python code to create function with Reversed arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295775/python-code-to-create-function-with-reversed-arguments)

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made an attempt, a decorator normally creates a closure over a function (using an inner function).